# double + double = String?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a problem the output is supposed to be double but instead it is string
I am trying to add two double values but it is giving it as a string. I am using eclipse. Currently the program is compiling and running. If anyone have a moment I would appreciate it.Cheers guys. Here is the source code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FutureInvestment 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter investment amount: ");
        double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter monthly interest rate: ");
        double monthlyInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter number of years: ");
        int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();

        double futureInterestValue = investmentAmount * ( Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), numberOfYears * 12));
        System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount);


    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the output I get Enter investment amount: 
1000
Enter monthly interest rate: 
4.25
Enter number of years: 
1
Accumulated value is: 4.384414858452464E111000.0

Comment: And the expected outcome is Accumulated value is 1043.34

Comment: I guess my answer can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your output. You can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or you can try the [String#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) function:

```
System.out.println(
    String.format("Accumulated value is: %.2f",
        futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount));
```

So you can get the 2 decimal output. Plus, I recommend to create a variable with your result, so you can turn your code into

```
double accumulatedValue = futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount;
 System.out.println(
    String.format("Accumulated value is: %.2f", accumulatedValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing it in a println, it's doing string concatenation. If you want to add the double's together, you need to group them using ().

Try

```
System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + (futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double accumulatedValue = futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount;
System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + accumulatedValue);
```

Try this.

You were getting String as result of concatenation, since anything concatenated to a string is converted to string. Therefore, you need to complete the value beforehand as I shown above, or you need parentheses.

Comment: same output: Accumulated value is: 4.384414868452464E11

Comment: If you mean the "E" inside the number, it is a double notation not an String

Answer (score 1):

I think change it to this would work:

```
    double futureInterestValue = investmentAmount * ( Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate / 100), numberOfYears * 12));
    System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + (futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount));
```

Comment: I am afraid it is not working I have the following output ==> Accumulated value is: 4.384414868452464E11

Comment: I think your calculation is wrong, you need to divide 100 on interest first, I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

you are missing some brackets, so your statement gets executed from left to right, thus appending the double to the string. You would need something like:

> System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + (futureInterestValue  +
>   investmentAmount));

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + (futureInterestValue  + investmentAmount));
```

After the first +, Java has concatenated the first string with the first double, resulting in a string. Then it does another concatenation with the second double. You need to calculate the result first before making a string out of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your number is getting way too large, and Java switches over to scientific notation when printing the value.

If your monthly interest rate is entered as 4.25 (meaning 4.25%), you have to convert that to the correct decimal representation of 0.0425 before using it in your calculations - you have to divide it by 100. If you don't, the interest rate used will be much larger than you intended; in this case 425%.

In other words, change

```
double monthlyInterestRate = input.nextDouble();
```

to

```
double monthlyInterestRate = input.nextDouble()/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

When two operators could be evaluated within a line of code, they do so with a fixed precedence.  While this example has been explained by many, [you might want to review all of the precedence rules.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + (futureInterestValue + investmentAmount));
```

or add a variable like `double accumulatedValue=futureInterestValue + investmentAmount;`
and then  `System.out.println("Accumulated value is: " + accumulatedValue);`